# PyCharm on Mac osx ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, macos, pycharm

idle PyCharm
os Mac osx
python 2.7
python3

Coding with PyCharm this error showed up..

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy', same with matplotlib and
>   other ones.

Any solution?

already changed interpreter to python3
it is working on bash terminal both python 2.7 and python3

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy
import matplotlib as plt
from matpololib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

style.use('ggplot')
```

Comment: You should install numpy in the environment which is used for your project. Try opening terminal in PyCharm and run `pip install numpy`.

Comment: tks I tried, answer You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: That's a warning not an error.

Comment: tks, working on terminal inside PyCharm it works ok. But how can I fix the error coding and run with the coding environment?

Comment: You should check in setiings->Project->Project interpreter the environment used for the project. You'll see installed packages there as well.

Comment: Also, you may check what python interpreter is used for running this particular script (in top right corner).

Comment: the interpreter are ok I have changed it and I can see NumPy, Matplotlib ....

Answer (score 0):

assume that you're using macOS with pyenv for different python versions.

Take the matplotlib stacked bar graph `bar_stacked.py` as the example (you could get the `.py` from  https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-bar-stacked-py).

**short answer: quickly configure pyenv python as this snapshot shows:**

[quick config steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLf3P.jpg)

**details**

1. open the bar_stacked.py with PyCharm;
2. check your python environment settings:

   - 2.1 check your python version with your terminal:

`ABC-MacBook-Pro:~ ABC$ which python
/Users/ABC/.pyenv/shims/python`

- 2.2 check your pyenv installed pythons

`ABC-MacBook-Pro:~ ABC$ pyenv versions
  system
* 3.7.0 (set by /Users/ABC/.python-version)`

- 2.3 confirm the python version you're using, here is Python 3.7.0

`ABC-MacBook-Pro:~ ABC$ python --version
Python 3.7.0`

3.configure the PyCharm interpreter as follows:

- 3.1 `PyCharm` -> `Preferences` -> `Project` -> `Project Interpreter`, you'll see a icon like a gear, click it and choose `Add...`
- 3.2 choose `Virtualenv Environment` on the left
- 3.3 choose `Existing environment` on the right, in the pop-up, locate the python i'm using as checked in step 2.1, here is `/Users/ABC/.pyenv/shims/python`
- 3.4 you can also check the box `Make available to all projects` if you want

finally, this example in PyCharm runs like this:

[running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G30jy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed the information of the popup when your mouse is hovering over the red waved underline? Just click "install matplotlib". Then it's ok.